# When is the trace of an integral element of an algebra integral?

Tags: abstract-algebra, trace, integral-extensions

Let $R$ be an integral domain, $K$ its field of fractions and $A$ a (unital, associative) $K$-algebra of finite dimension. Call $a \in A$ integral (over $R$) if it is a root of a monic polynomial with coefficients in $R$.

> (When) does this imply that the trace of $a$ (trace of the linear map $x \mapsto ax$) lies in $R$?

It is certainly true if $R$ is a PID: take any finitely generated $R$-submodule $M \subset A$ that is stable by $a$ and generates $A$ over $K$. (E.g.: take any free $R$-submodule $N$ that generates $A$ over $K$ and take $M = R[a] N$.) Because $R$ is a PID, it is free, necessarily of rank $\dim_K A$ and one can then compute the trace of $A$ w.r.t. a basis of $M$.

In the general case, it would suffice to find a free $R$-submodule that is stable by $a$ and generates $A$ over $K$. I don't know if that exists.

Comment: Do you already know the proof when $A$ is a field and $R$ is normal?

Comment: Also, if $x \in A$ is such that $K[x]$ is a field and has minimal polynomial in $R[X]$ (equivalent, when $R$ is a UFD, to $x$ being integral with an irreducible minimal polynomial), then $A$ is a finite-dimensional $K[x]$-vector space and by writing multiplication by $x$ in a suitable basis, you find a trace in $R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trace of $a$ is always integral over $R$.

Indeed, pick any basis $\left(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\right)$ of the finite-dimensional $K$-vector space $A$. Let $L_a : A \to A$ be the $K$-linear map sending each $b \in A$ to $ab$. This map $L_a$ is an endomorphism of the $K$-vector space $A$, and thus can be represented by a square matrix over $K$ (with respect to the basis $\left(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\right)$). Let $M_a$ be this matrix. Of course, the trace of $a$ equals the trace of $L_a$ (by definition), which in turn equals the trace of $M_a$ (by definition).

The matrix $M_a$ is integral over $R$ (since the same monic polynomial over $R$ that annihilates $a$ will annihilate $L_a$ and thus annihilate $M_a$). It thus remains to prove that if a matrix over $K$ is integral over $R$, then so is its trace. But this is a particular case of Corollary 1.26 in

- [Alberto Dennunzio, Enrico Formenti, Darij Grinberg, Luciano Margara, *Integrality of matrices, finiteness of matrix semigroups, and dynamics of linear cellular automata*, arXiv:1907.08565v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.08565v1).

Comment: You still need $R$ to be normal for your proof to work, no?

Comment: @Mindlack: Oh, right, because I answered the question in the title and not in the question...

Comment: Thanks, so in fact even the entire characteristic polynomial of $a$ has coefficients that are integral over $R$.

Comment: @Mindlack Well, if $a \in A$ is integral over the integral closure of $R$, then it is integral over $R$, so normality should not matter.

Comment: @punctureddusk: You're welcome! Mindlack's comment referred to the first revision of my answer, which was ambiguous in its claim.

Comment: Ok :) I just realized that in Bourbaki, Algèbre Commutative, Chapter V §1.6, Proposition 17 it is also shown that the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of an integral matrix are integral.

Comment: Wow! I thought I had looked in Bourbaki. And they're using polynomial integrality (Proposition 12 in §1.3), which for some reason I thought was false.

Comment: The argument is short enough to be written in full, no? Basically, your matrix $M$ is similar in some algebraic closure of $K$ to a triangular matrix $T$. The monic polynomial $P$ in $R$ that vanishes at $M$ vanishes at $T$ too, so all of the diagonal entries of $T$, being roots of $P$, are integral over $R$. So the coefficients of $\chi_T=\chi_M$ are polynomials with integer coefficients in the diagonal entries of $T$, and polynomials with integer coefficents in the entries of $M$, so are in $K$ and integral over $R$, so if $R$ is normal are in $R$.

Comment: @Mindlack: My argument is less short but more general (you are relying on $K$ being a field).

Answer (score 2):

That’s not a complete answer, but it is fairly general, so worth writing.

Let $R$ be a ring satisfying the following property: every monic divisor in $K[X]$ of a monic polynomial in $R[X]$ is in $R[X]$ (in particular, $R$ must be normal, and any UFD works).

Then, consider, for some integral $x \in A$, the matrix $M$ of $a \in A \longmapsto ax$ in any basis. It is similar to a matrix $B$ diagonal by blocks, with the blocks being Frobenius matrices associated with monic divisors of the minimal polynomial of $x$, ie associated with monic divisors in $K[X]$ of a monic annihilating polynomial of $x$ in $R[X]$.

As a consequence, by the property of $R$, $B$ has coefficients in $R$, and thus the trace of $x$, which is the trace of $M$, so the trace of $B$, is in $R$.

Comment: I'm interested in the case where $R$ is a Dedekind domain, so I can live with that condition. So, the blocks arise by decomposing $A$ into irreducible $K[a]$-modules, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Wait, no. Sorry, how do you construct those blocks?

Comment: Mostly I’m using https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form .

Comment: Thanks! So you decompose $M$ as a $K[a]$-module but viewed as a $K[X]$-module, using the structure theorem for $K[X]$.

Comment: (Off-topic) This is weird, I just read Bourbaki, Algèbre Commutative Chapter V, §1.3, Proposition 11 which says: "Let $A$ be a ring, $R$ an $A$-algebra, $P$ and $Q$ monic in $R[X]$. If $PQ$ has coefficients that are integral over $A$, then so do $P$ and $Q$." Taking $A$ an integrally closed integral domain and $R$ its fraction field, this means that $A$ satisfies your condition. But that seems to strong to be true.

Comment: No, this implies my condition only when $R$ is normal, else you can have divisors in $K[X]$, not in $R[X]$, but with integral coefficients over $R[X]$.

Comment: Ah, so it is true that $R$ normal implies your condition?

Comment: I guess so, provided the claim from Bourbaki is true.

Comment: Yes, that claim from Bourbaki is true (and is a consequence of Theorem 6 in [Thierry Coquand, Henrik Persson, *Valuations and Dedekind's Prague Theorem*](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(99)00095-X)).